# How to tell @babel/core about external build variables

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, babeljs, babel-jest

I have a React project built using Webpack, in which I'm defining some buildtime variables using Webpack's DefinePlugin:

```
plugins: [
  new DefinePlugin({
    __ENV__: argv.mode,
    // ...
  })
]
```

I reference this variable in some of my code files like so:

```
if(__ENV__ === 'production') {
  // ...
}
```

But the problem is that the `@babel/core` package complains about undefined variables. Strangely enough, the `babel-core` npm package used to recognize the variables if I defined them at the top of the file like this:

```
declare var __ENV__;
```

But when switching to the `@babel/core` package this gives the error

```
SyntaxError Unexpected token, expected ";" (6:8)
declare var __ENV__;
        ^
```

Is there a way to tell the `@babel/core` package about external variables?

Comment: "But the problem is that the @babel/core package complains about undefined variables." What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

According to your last snippet, there is a syntax error and not a problem with an external variable:

```js
SyntaxError Unexpected token, expected ";" (6:8)
declare var __ENV__;
        ^
```

The word `declare` is not a javascript keyword, it is the flow/typescript
keyword. Are you using flow/typescript babel presets in your build process?